# iterate over two lists in NetLogo: Big picture context :R extension. Assign patch values to specific patches from R

Tags: r, netlogo

I need to pass some data to `R` from `NetLogo` using the `R-extension`, do some computations and then assign the `R` output to specific patches.

I have tried every combination of `map` and `foreach` in `NetLogo` that I can imagine. I have been trying to change colors based on a patch id because it is visible. Setting all of the patches blue works.

```
observer> foreach [1 2 3] [ x -> ask patches with [id = x] [ set pcolor blue ] ]
```

When I add the second list nothing I have tried works. I also tried assigning values to the patches to no avail. This turned patches 4, 5, and 6 red...

```
observer> foreach [4 5 6] [ x -> ask patches with [id = x] [ set pcolor [blue red green] ]]
```

The next approach did not work.

```
observer> set list-a (list blue red green)
observer> set list-b (list 7 8 9)
observer> ask patches with [id = list-b] [ set pcolor list-a]
```

Attempting a foreach with two lists like this:

```
observer> foreach list-b list-b ask patches with [id = list-b] [set pcolor list-a]
observer> show map list-b list-b ask patches with [id = list-b] [set pcolor list-a]
```

redefining list-a and then trying the original approach again sets those patches blue.

```
observer> set list-a r:get "df1[[1]]"
observer> show list-a
observer: [1 5 8]
observer> foreach list-a [ x -> ask patches with [id = x] [ set pcolor blue ] ]
```

If I could just understand how to work through two lists I would be set.

for example

```
list-a [1 2 3]
list-b [blue green red]

; effectively do the following

ask patch with [id = 1] [set pcolor blue]
ask patch with [id = 2] [set pcolor green]
ask patch with [id = 3] [set pcolor red]
```

The actual problem is I have activity variables (all the patches below are planting corn).

```r
> a
   id a_corn a_crp a_soy
1   1      0     1     0
2   2      0     1     0
3   3      0     1     0
4   4      0     1     0
5   5      0     1     0
6   6      0     1     0
7   7      0     1     0
8   8      0     1     0
9   9      0     1     0
10 10      0     1     0
>
```

I know with the r extension dataframes come into netlogo as unnamed nested lists. So if I avoid the nesting by:

```
set list-id r:get "a$id"
set list-a r:get "a$a_corn"
; then netlogo iterates through the lists:
ask patch with [id = 1] [set a_corn 0]
ask patch with [id = 2] [set a_corn 0]
; and so on
```

I am open to suggestions for better ways. But the ids need to match, may not be sequential, and the a dataframe above will vary in size and contents.

**UPDATE:
As I continue working the problem I am documenting the steps here so I can find them later.**

I have found anonymous-commands.

```
observer> set procedure [[x y] -> ask patches with [id = x] [set pcolor y]]
observer> show  is-anonymous-command? procedure
observer: true
observer> set list-a (list blue red green)
observer> set list-b (list 7 8 9)
observer> (foreach list-b list-a procedure) ; does nothing
```

I cleared all, set up again and the following worked:

```
observer> ask patches with [id = 7] [set pcolor red]
observer> set procedure [[x y] -> ask patches with [id = x] [set pcolor y]]
observer> set list-b (list 7 8 9)
observer> set list-a (list blue red green)
observer> (foreach list-b list-a procedure)
```

Now for the application portion of the problem:

```
observer> set procedure [[x y] -> ask patches with [id = x] [set a_corn y]]
observer> set list-a (list 1 1 1)
observer> (foreach list-b list-a procedure)
```

and it works!

Comment: Is any of the r-extension stuff relevant to this question? I think you are simply asking about iterating over two lists but it's not very clear. Please provide example data: what you would provide and the expected output.

Comment: I am not sure the r extension stuff is needed, but I wanted to provide context on the chance that there is a better way to complete the entire operation. So as for examples:
```
patches-own [id a_corn]



set list-id [1 4 6]
set list-a [0 1 0]
;then I want it to:
ask patch with [id = 1] [set a_corn 0]
ask patch with [id = 4] [set a_corn 1]
ask patch with [id = 6] [set a_corn 0]
```
basically, the last three code blocks after I say "If I could just understand how to work through two lists I would be set."